# Extracting the second largest and minimum values, and plot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, sorting

How to extract the second lowest and the second largest values of each row, and plot them as upper and lower graphs? I try with `TakeLargest` (or `TakeSmallest`) as [discussed here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/241012/75304),
but I do not want them sorted in ascending/descending order.

I want the graph to be like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/266594/75304). Yes, we can do that with `Min, Max, Mean`. But how to manipulate/extract any data that I could have without changing the originality of its order?

Here is some example of the data.

```
data={{0.3,0.538102,0.760004,0.895921,0.959015,0.984521,0.99425,0.997877,0.999218,0.185006,0.381593},

{0.3,0.538102,0.760004,0.895921,0.959015,0.984521,0.99425,0.180053,0.37379,0.618694,0.815178},                

{0.3,0.538102,0.760004,0.895921,0.959015,0.984521,0.99425,0.997877,0.999218,0.999712,0.999894},                

{0.3,0.538102,0.760004,0.895921,0.959015,0.984521,0.99425,0.997877,0.522662,0.748515,0.889997},                

{0.3,0.538102,0.760004,0.895921,0.959015,0.984521,0.99425,0.997877,0.999218,0.568709,0.781868},                

{0.3,0.538102,0.760004,0.895921,0.959015,0.984521,0.99425,0.997877,0.999218,0.999712,0.105905},                

{0.3,0.538102,0.760004,0.895921,0.959015,0.984521,0.99425,0.491513,0.724331,0.877186,0.951017},                

{0.3,0.538102,0.760004,0.895921,0.959015,0.984521,0.99425,0.451753,0.691344,0.858927,0.943021},                

{0.3,0.538102,0.760004,0.895921,0.959015,0.984521,0.99425,0.997877,0.999218,0.999712,0.0995195},                

{0.3,0.538102,0.760004,0.895921,0.959015,0.984521,0.43541,0.677037,0.850711,0.939357,0.976801}};
```

I do try with `MaximalBy`, but I don't think my extraction technique is correct. I'm not expecting any overlap between upper and lower graphs.

```
Show[
 ListLinePlot[Mean[MaximalBy[data, Last, 6]], PlotRange -> Full, 
  DataRange -> {0, 30}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 ListLinePlot[Mean[MinimalBy[data, First, 4]], PlotRange -> Full, 
  DataRange -> {0, 30}, PlotStyle -> Blue]
 ]
```

[image]

This sample does not vary much, but it was part of a larger dataset.

Thanks in advance for the guidance and help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ListLinePlot[{
  RankedMax[#, 2] & /@ data,
  RankedMin[#, 2] & /@ data
  }]
```

Comment: I was not aware of `Ranked*` functions. Thanks. Your solution is quite elegant. I guess it would also work with jagged arrays as well whereas a `Transpose` based solution would not.

Answer (score 3):

With `data` as presented in the OP, the second lowest and the second highest entries (`slsh`) in the Sorted data are:

```
slsh = Transpose[#[[{2, -2}]] & /@ (Sort /@ data)]

ListLinePlot[slsh
 , PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}
   , {Thick, Red}
   }
 , Mesh -> All
 , Filling -> 1 -> {2}
 ]
```

[image]

---

```
alldata = Transpose[(Sort /@ data)]
```

[image]

Comment: The filling region helps to highlight the area of interest. Is it possible to calculate the percentage of the shaded area? **Note: Thank you for showing the method with ```Transpose``` & ```Sort``` to plot the region, I couldn't think of that.

Comment: % of the area compared to what? The entire area? I think you can start a fresh post with this query. First, the shaded area will have to be converted to a polygon. Then the same will be done with the entire area before a percentage can be calculated. I say this because it is a general policy on stack sites to limit the Q/A to one focused discussion per page.

Comment: Yes, I'll work on the problem, perhaps one with a more interesting dataset, and post another question. On another note, your answer here does help, but I may have to accept Henrik's for now

Comment: @nightcape That is the better answer for sure.